# Read a file specified as an argument and return its' lines

Tags: c, file, fgets, stdio

I have an exercise in which I have to read a file containing strings and I have to return the content using one/multiple arrays (this is because the second part of this exercise asks for these lines to be reversed, I'm having problems - and therefore ask for help - with the input).
So far, I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char* input[LENGTH];

    if(argc==2){

        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rt");

        if(fp!=NULL){

            int i=0;
            while(fgets(input, sizeof(input), fp)!=NULL){
                input[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (LENGTH));
                fgets(input, sizeof(input), fp);
                i++;
            }
            printf("%s", *input);
            free(input);

        }
        else{
            printf("File opening unsuccessful!");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Enter an argument.");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I also have to check whether or not memory allocation has failed. This program in its' current form returns nothing when run from the command line.

EDIT: I think it's important to mention that I get a number of warnings:

`passing argument 1 of 'fgets' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]|`

`attempt to free a non-heap object 'input' [-Wfree-nonheap-object]|`

EDIT 2:
Example of input:

```
These
are
strings
```

... and the expected output:

```
esehT
era
sgnirts
```

In the exercise, it's specified that the maximum length of a line is `1024` characters.

Comment: You seem to be using the variable `input` for two different things: 1) As a buffer foir `fgets`; And 2) as an array of strings. You can't have it both ways, you can only use it for one thing. You need *two* variables: One for the buffer used for `fgets` and a separate variable used for the strings.

Comment: Also, you seem to misunderstand how arrays and pointers in general work. You can't print all elements of an array using a single `printf` call, you must use a loop. And be careful not to pass the end of the initialized parts of the array. Similarly, you can't pass `input` to `free` and hope it will free all allocated pointers in it. Again you need a loop, and only loop over the pointers you actually allocated.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't really need an array of strings *at all* in your code. All you need is the single buffer for `fgets`, which you print in the same loop as you read the input. So no need for pointers or dynamic allocation.

Comment: Lastly, you read *two* lines per iteration of the loop. Skipping every other line, and ignoring its contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this.

Comments are in the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  if (argc == 2) {

    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "rt");

    if (fp != NULL) {
      char** lines = NULL;         // pointer to pointers to lines read
      int nboflines = 0;           // total number of lines read

      char input[LENGTH];          // temporary input buffer

      while (fgets(input, sizeof(input), fp) != NULL) {
        char* newline = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);        // allocate memory for line (+1 for null terminator)
        strcpy(newline, input);                           // copy line just read
        newline[strcspn(newline, "\n")] = 0;              // remove \n if any
        nboflines++;                                      // one more line
        lines = realloc(lines, nboflines * sizeof(char*)); // reallocate memory for one more line
        lines[nboflines - 1] = newline;                    // store the pointer to the line
      }

      fclose(fp);

      for (int i = 0; i < nboflines; i++)    // print the lins we've read
      {
        printf("%s\n", lines[i]);
      }
    }
    else {
      printf("File opening unsuccessful!");
    }
  }
  else {
    printf("Enter an argument.");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Explanation about removing the `\n` left by `fgets`: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Disclaimers:

- there is no error checking for the memory allocation functions
- memory is not freed. This is left as an exercise.
- the way `realloc` is used here is not very efficient.
- you still need to write the code that reverses each line and displays it.

You probably should decompose this into different functions:

- a function that reads the file and returns the pointer to the lines and  the number of lines read,
- a function that displays the lines read
- a function that reverses one line (to be written)
- a function that reverses all lines (to be written)

This is left as an exercise.